# Php & css on wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Basically I have a price ticker in my header.php (wordpress) file aligned to the left.

Its just below the main menu and above the slider. The problem I am having now is I want to put the ticker aligned next to my main menu aligned to the right. I want the menu to end and the ticker to follow... I think i should have to edit the css file to do this but I'm not totally sure. The ticker is in .php also.

I have successfully gotten the ticker to the right of the page almost where I want it but its not aligning with the menu...

I have attached a screen shot to show what I mean but due to privacy reason iv edited out alot of the website information.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHk2q.jpg

Any help will be seriously appreciated. :)

Comment: I hope you're not modifying wordpress core files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust your code to float it left and adjust the width so that it fits the place where you'd like to put it.

Comment: If you are calling it from another website, you can wrap it inside of a div that fits it all and then apply styles onto that div. You would use: float:left; width:100px; (or whatever width you want to give it so that it fits.

Comment: Can you post some of the code?

Comment: Phew, you have some code there.

Okay. Do you know CSS fluently?

Comment: No I don't at all :( Im only learning!

Comment: I suggest that you get a web designer or something like that. Wordpress can become really difficult for people who don't know how to code at all. I hope that you find some usefulness in my answers. Remember, wrap the ticket into a <div></div> and then apply classes to that div so that it does what you want it to do, in this case... Float left.

Comment: Thanks Tiffany, appreciate your help a lot ill try figure it out thanks again!

Comment: Done, tried to give you rep but the site wont allow me to yet as I am new.